# Allow access to file only from specific Lambda [s3]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

A s3 bucket (static web hosting) have a certain policy that deny access to everyone concerning a certain file.

How can I **allow only** a specific **lambda function** to access it ? (using only the bucket policy)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "Authentication",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action": "s3:GetObject",
          "NotResource": "arn:aws:s3:::web/auth.html"
      }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE** : Changing the previous policy with this one gives the desired result

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1477651215159",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Console administration",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/role_lambda"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "NotResource": "arn:aws:s3:::web/auth.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda functions run in a Execution Role. You can make a customer IAM Role for your lambda function. See [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html)

Then you can use that IAM Role to grant access to that S3 Object. See this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/) for steps to follow.

Comment: thanks for this solution, but I want to use only the bucket policy

Comment: You should be able to do this with a bucket policy as well.  Just post the ARN of the Lambda Role : `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/example_role_for_lambda` into your bucket policy.  It goes into the `Principal` node.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `CloudFormation` snippet. You can allow your `Lambda` role access to `S3` using the following `IAM` policy statement:

```
"LambdaRolePolicy" : {
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
    "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "Lambda",
        "PolicyDocument": {
            "Statement" : [ {
                "Action" : [
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:PutObjectAcl"
                ],
                "Effect" : "Allow",
                "Resource" : {
                    "Fn::Join": [ "", [
                        "arn:aws:s3:::",
                        { "Ref": "S3Bucket" },
                        "/*"
                    ] ]
                }
            } ]
        },
        "Roles" : [ { "Ref": "RootRole" } ]
    }
}
```

`S3Bucket` resource is your `S3` bucket and `RootRole` is the `Lambda` role.